# Single thick green/red vertical line on iMac display

Tags: macos, mac, imac, gpu

I started seeing a single green/red color line on my iMac. Is it a common problem? How can I fix it. It also vanishes after some time but comes back again. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Does the line stay the same color all the way to the top? In the image it seems to end at the top of the mountains? Making a flat background / neutral gray might help determine the colors being drawn without a macro lens photo.

Comment: Take a screen shot, is it in the screen shot? If no then it is likely an issue with the display. If it IS in the screenshot it is likely an issue with the GPU. Depending on the model it *might* be repairable without replacing the system board.